# Syntax error with FIRST_VALUE function in HANA CDS

Tags: hana, sql-function, hana-cds

I am working in SAP HANA Native CDS, where i want to convert a sql query into CDS format.

The current SQL Query looks like this

```
FIRST_VALUE(STAT) OVER(PARTITION BY OBJNR ORDER BY UDATE desc, UTIME desc) as STAT,
FIRST_VALUE(UDATE) OVER(PARTITION BY OBJNR ORDER BY UDATE desc, UTIME desc)  as CHG_DATE
```

I now tried to convert this into HANA CDS like this

```
view V_MYVIEW as select from TABLE
{
OBJNR,
FIRST_VALUE(STAT) OVER(PARTITION BY OBJNR ORDER BY UDATE desc, UTIME desc) as STAT,
FIRST_VALUE(UDATE) OVER(PARTITION BY OBJNR ORDER BY UDATE desc, UTIME desc)  as CHG_DATE
};
```

> Syntax error: unexpected token "(" at line 36, column 12

but the code throws an error at `(` and `)`. 
Is there any other way to achieve this in the CDS??

Best Regards,
Gabriel.

Comment: Are you missing the `DEFINE` command in `DEFINE view V_MYVIEW as select ...` ? Also, could you please provide a minimal working example with a simple table where all columns are known? For example UDATE and UTIME are not defined anywhere yet.

Comment: Hello Konstantin , this is native hana CDS , the view is fine working without the following statements FIRST_VALUE(STAT) OVER(PARTITION BY OBJNR ORDER BY UDATE desc, UTIME desc) as STAT,
FIRST_VALUE(UDATE) OVER(PARTITION BY OBJNR ORDER BY UDATE desc, UTIME desc)  as CHG_DATE

Comment: The table name i masked here is JCDS

Answer (score 2):

These analytical/window-functions are not supported by HANA CDS in HANA 2 SPS 04.
If you want to use those, you may have to resort to table functions or SQL views.